# How download all dependency to local using bazel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel

I have a project which is built with bazel. When I open the project with vs-code, I find that many header files cannot be found, for example:
    `#include <grpc++/grpc++.h>`
but the build is successful. I think it is due to the dependency on bazel,

```
        remote_workspace(
            name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
            remote = "https://github.com/grpc/grpc",
            tag = "1.21.3",
            patches = ["@//bazel/patches:grpc.patch"],
            patch_args = ["-p1"],
        )
```

Is there any way to download all bazel dependencies to my local machine, so that vs-code can find all files?

Comment: I am getting "could not find <grpc++/grpc++.h> errors. Did you get this one before? @dingrui

Answer (score 3):

If the build succeeded, the files are already on your machine. You just have to tell vs-code where.

Bazel materializes all external repositories under `<execution_root>/external/`. The `<execution_root>` is a directory Bazel creates in its output tree, and you can find its path by running `bazel info execution_root`. Under that, you'll see `external/`, and under that you'll find the repositories.

However, you probably have to give vs-code a static path, not a command. Luckily, there's a more convenient way. Look at your workspace directory after the build: see the `bazel-bin` and other `bazel-*` directories? These are actually symlinks, and one of them is called something like `bazel-myproject`, where "myproject" is the name of your workspace directory. This symlink also points to the `<execution_root>`, so you can tell vs-code to look for headers under `bazel-myproject/external/com_github_grpc_grpc`.